# Neo4j incorporate where path size is greater than 3 into my query that has 2 distinct node labels defined

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following query returns nodes and relationships of emails that where attempted to be sent containing a link or an attachment and failed to be delivered to a recipient.

```
MATCH (s:Sender)-[:ATTEMPTED]->(x)-[:FAILED_TO]->(r:Recipient)
WHERE x:Link OR x:Attachment
return s,x,r
```

I would like to modify this so that I can say there where more than 3 recipients in the chain by adding something like:

```
WITH a, COLLECT(path) AS paths
WHERE SIZE(paths) > 3
RETURN paths
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
MATCH (s:Sender)-[:ATTEMPTED]->(x)
WHERE size((x)-[:FAILED_TO]->()) > 3 AND (x:Link OR x:Attachment)
MATCH (x)-[:FAILED_TO]->(r:Recipient)
return s,x,r
```

So you first query for x nodes, which have more than 3 FAILED_TO relationships. After you find them you search for their recipients.